# Python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, camera

I am getting an error that says :
Camera component couldnt be enabled: `Out of resources (other than memory)` or `Incorrect buffer length for resolution` when I run the following code:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import io
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy as mp
import math

camera=PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(640,480)
camera.framerate=1
cap=PiRGBArray(camera,size=(640,480))
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(cap,format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
    img=frame.array
    cv2.imshow('input',img)
```

Comment: Did you see this similar question? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26829/picamera-not-working

Comment: Tried... None of them are working

Comment: The first suspicion is that it's some hardware issue. Do you get errors or success when you run `raspistill` from the command line? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspistill.md

Comment: success. It takes a picture and is saving it.